# Having a fixed response URL from plotly live stream plot

Tags: node.js, real-time, live-streaming, plotly

I intend to plot my live-streaming data. Using plotly https://github.com/chintanp/node_serial_uC/blob/master/stream_hum.js works and I can get the data plotted and updating in real-time at a unique (and random) URL like https://plot.ly/~chintanp/107 (this is an example response url, might not work right now), but this url which I get in the response to the function call `plotly.plot(...)` changes to a new value with every new run of my server.

Is there a way I can set this URL to a fixed value, so that it doesnt change everytime I restart my node server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is overwrite or extend an existing plot at a fixed filename. This way each time you call `Plotly.plot` it will write to the same plot in the DB which is accessible at a fixed URL. The way to achieve this with the current version 1 API (the one you are using) is to pass in the same `filename` for each run.

```
var plotly = require('plotly')('username','apiKey');

var data = [{x:[], y:[], stream:{token:'yourStreamtoken', maxpoints:200}}];
var graphOptions = {fileopt : "overwrite", filename : "yourfilename"};

plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function() {
    var stream = plotly.stream('yourStreamtoken', function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });

    someReadableStream.pipe(stream);
});
```

Every time you start your server `"yourfilename"` should be the same. Also note that `fileopt` is set to `"overwrite"`. This will clear any existing data in the stream buffer. If you set `fileopt` to `"extend"` it will append new data you are streaming onto whatever data still remained from your previous run.

I find that during development it is best to use `"overwrite"` while in production it usually makes sense to use `"extend"` (so that you can recover from tcp disconnects).

Comment: Great!, `overwrite` is the key change here, as I am already using the same  `filename` option. `new` creates a new url each time and new file name while `overwrite` does as advertised. I wasnt able to test `extend` though as when I restarted the server, the new time was far ahead, and plotly had lost all the previous data, apparently the "PAN" feature, doesnt work for data off-screen. So, data-persistence has to be separately addressed.